# Salt stack execute a command/invoke a different state upon state failure

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to run multiple states in a sls file and I have a requirement to execute a command upon failure of a state.

e.g.

```
    test_cmd1:
        cmd.run:
          - name: |
               echo 'Command 1'

    test_cmd2:
        cmd.run:
          - name: |
               echo 'Command 2'

    on_fail_command:
        cmd.run:
          - name: |
                echo 'On failure'
                exit 1
```

I want on_fail_command to be executed when any of test_cmd1 or test_cmd2 fails... but not run when both test commands successfully execute. I have **failHard** set to True globally in our system.

I tried using **onfail** but that does not behave the way I want. onfail executes a state if any of the state listed under onfail fails, but here I am looking to skip executing other states upon a state fail but instead jump to on_fail_command and then exit.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `order`  of your `on_fail_command` state so it runs before anything else, and `failhard` so it fails the whole job.